# A Question for the AGES

Tags: knowledge, visual

To properly complete this image, what color should the central S be?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be

> blue

because

> these are the first names of several Sonic The Hedgehog characters, colored with those characters' colors. (We have **B**ig the Cat, **K**nuckles the Echidna, **S**onic the Hedgehog, **T**ails the Fox, and **S**hadow the Hedgehog.)
>
>  The title hints at this because AGES is the reverse of SEGA, the company that made the Sonic series.